# Python: change rows in txt to columns

Tags: python, txt

I have txt file like this:

```
     Name  |  Class  |  Points
     --------------------------
     Name1 |    (2)    |  30
     Name1 |    (3)    |  50
     Name1 |    (5)    |  15
     Name2 |    (1)    |  25
     Name2 |    (3)    |  88
     Name2 |    (4)    |  3
```

Classes are from 1 - 100
I would like to change this table into-

```
           |  (1)  |  (2)  |  (3) | ...

     Name1 |   ..  |  30   |  50  |

     Name2 |   25  |   ..  |  88  |
```

So far I have file with **header** and **Names**, but I can't figure out how to put data in proper place, proper column.

```
     f = open("file.txt", "r")
     classes = set()
     names = set()
     for line in f:
         line = line.split("\t")
         if line[1] == "Class":
             continue
         else:
             classes.add(int(line[1]))
         names.add(line[0])
     sorted(classes)
     print(classes)
     with open("new_file.txt", "a") as file:
         for i in classes:
             file.write(f"\t{i}")
         for j in names:
             file.write(f"\n{j}")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What output are you getting? Edit your question. See how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You can use two-dimensional array, using this data structure you can access data by [row][col].In you case, if you want to change rows to columns, access by [col][row].

In python, [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is the answer.

Here's the sample code:

```py
import collections

# use defaultdict to store data accessed by [row][col]
data = collections.defaultdict(dict)

# read data
columns = set()
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        row, col, value = line.split()
        if col == 'Class':
            continue
        data[row][col] = value
        columns.add(col)

# sort columns and rows
columns = sorted(columns)
rows = sorted(data.keys())

# write data
with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    header = '\t' + '\t'.join(columns) + '\n'
    lines = [header]
    for row in rows:
        parts = [row]
        for col in columns:
            v = data[row].get(col)
            if v:
                parts.append(v)
            else:
                parts.append('..')
        lines.append('\t'.join(parts) + '\n')
    f.writelines(lines)
```